# How to detect before dropped selected text into input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

As usual you can drop selected text from anywhere into inputs. I want to do something when cursor into an input. ex: if I selected some text then I dragged into an input, but I don't dropping into that input. But input making the cursor and the cursor icon has been changed to plus icon, I want to do function at that time!

[image]

```js
$("input").on("beforeDROP", function(){
//do something
});
```

```css
    form input {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <form>
        <p>some text</p>
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dragover` and `dragstart` events to listen for these events.

Attaching a `dragstart` listener to the `document` will fire whenever any selected text is dragged on the page.

If you add a `dragover` listener to your text input you'll be able to detect when the selected text is being dragged over it:

```js
let textInput = document.getElementById('text-input');

textInput.addEventListener("dragover", (event) => {
  // prevent default to allow drop
  event.preventDefault();
  
  console.log('dragging over input');
}, false);


document.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
  console.log('dragging');
}, false);
```

```css
form input {
  font-size: 16px;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>some text</p>
  <input type="text" id="text-input" />
</form>
```

Comment: When drag over  the input, the output is coming 100 times! how to drag over for one time call?